# How do I pass an extra variable to Jquery Autocomplete field in souce?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
$( "#location" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'property-location/?city=' + $('[name=city]').val() + $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: The `source:` property can be a function, which can then perform an AJAX request with the computed URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass function into suorce instead of api url.

```
$("#location").autocomplete({
    source: 'property-location/?city=' + $('[name=city]').val() + $(this).val(),
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON('property-location/', {
            term: extractLast(request.term),
            city: $('[name=city]').val()
        }, response);
    }
});
```